Evaluate $I_m = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{nm} \frac{i^2n^3}{n^6 + i^6}$ and $\lim_{m \to \infty} I_m$
I am trying to find
$$I_m = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{nm} \frac{i^2n^3}{n^6 + i^6}$$
where m is positive integer, and then find the $$\lim_{m \to \infty} I_m$$
I have tried this problem by simplifying the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^{nm} \frac{i^2n^3}{n^6 + i^6}$$
to
$$\sum_{i=1}^{nm} \frac{i^2}{n^3(1+(\frac{i}{n})^6)}$$
and how can I do the following step?

Please go through this to check if I am doing right:
Consider the function
$$f_m(x) = \frac{(mx)^2}{1+(mx)^6}.$$
This is integrable on $[0,1]$. Divide the interval $[0,1]$ into $nm$ equal parts so that you will get the partition:
$$\lbrace\frac{1}{nm}, \frac{2}{nm},\dots, \frac{nm-1}{nm}, 1\rbrace.$$
A Riemann sum (specifically upper Darboux sum) for $f_m(x)$ for this partition would be the following:
$$\frac{1}{nm}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{nm} \frac{i^2/n^2}{1+i^6/n^6} = \frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{nm}\frac{n^3i^2}{n^6+i^6}.$$
Thus,
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{nm}\frac{n^3i^2}{n^6+i^6} = m\int\limits_{0}^1f_m(x)\, dx. $$
Now,
$$\int\limits_{0}^1 f_m(x)\,dx=\int\limits_{0}^1 \frac{(mx)^2}{1+(mx)^6}\, dx = \frac{1}{3m}\tan^{-1}(m^3x^3)\Large|_{0}^1.$$
Thus,
$$I_m = \frac{1}{3}\tan^{-1}(m^3).$$
Hence,
$$\lim\limits_{m\to \infty} I_m = \frac{\pi}{6}.$$
